# How to display all my scheme names in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display all my scheme name(GROUP A, GROUP B and GROUP C) in my SCHEME column.
If all the value of STATUS column is N then the criteria should be empty.

**Mytable:**

[image: screenshot of mytable]

Here is my query (i am using oracle)

```
SELECT SCHEME,  LISTAGG(CRITERIA, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BYCRITERIA) AS CRITERIA
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE STATUS = 'Y'
GROUP BY SCHEME
```

**My result**

[image: screenshot of the output]

**Result that i am expecting**

[image: i want my output to be like this]

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SCHEME,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Y' THEN CRITERIA END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BYCRITERIA) AS CRITERIA
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY SCHEME
```